# No Order matches the given query

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am learning Django from book called Django 3 by example. I am following steps given in the book. But I am getting following error:

```
Page not found (404)
No Order matches the given query.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/payment/process/
Raised by:  payment.views.payment_process
Using the URLconf defined in FlixKart.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
cart/
orders/
payment/ process/ [name='process']
The current path, payment/process/, matched the last one.
```

**views.py** of payments app:

```
def payment_process(request):
    order_id = request.session.get('order_id')
    order = get_object_or_404(Order, id=order_id)
    total_cost = order.get_total_cost()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # retrieve nonce
        nonce = request.POST.get('payment_method_nonce', None)
        # create and submit transaction
        result = gateway.transaction.sale({
            'amount': f'{total_cost:.2f}',
            'payment_method_nonce': nonce,
            'options': {
                'submit_for_settlement': True
            }
        })
        if result.is_success:
            # mark the order as paid
            order.paid = True
            # store the unique transaction id
            order.braintree_id = result.transaction.id
            order.save()
            return redirect('payment:done')
        else:
            return redirect('payment:canceled')
    else:
        # generate token
        client_token = gateway.client_token.generate()
        return render(request, 'payment/process.html', {'order': order,'client_token': client_token})
```

**url patterns from urls.py of Project:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('cart/', include('cart.urls', namespace='cart')),
    path('orders/', include('orders.urls', namespace='orders')),
    path('payment/', include('payment.urls', namespace='payment')),
    path('', include('shop.urls', namespace='shop')),

]
```

I have tried some solutions from stackoverflow but none worked for me.
Please help me solve this error.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you put your urls list into settings?

Comment: Yes I have done that

Comment: It's needed to be put in `urls.py` file. I suggest you to try to pass tutorial, Django's tutorial is really good https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: Sorry. It is already in urls.py of the project. I just wrongly mentioned that I have put urls in settings.py. But it is already in urls.py

Answer (score 0):

The page is resolved correctly, but the error `No Order matches the given query` hints the 404 is caused by the following line.

```
order = get_object_or_404(Order, id=order_id)
```

That means the record with ID matching `order_id` does not exists in the database, or the value is empty.

Comment: Okay. But what would be the possible solution for this?

Comment: you should be able to answer this question yourself - dont get into the situation where you have invalid `order_id` in the session